# how to download large mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database-backups

in my case database is almost more than 2GB so its taking too much time so how to break it down any idea please help `backup_tables('localhost','xyz','xyz','xyz');

function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name)
{
    $link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$name);

```
if($tables == '*')
{
    $tables = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SHOW TABLES');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        $tables[] = $row[0];}
    }
else{ $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);}

//cycle through
foreach($tables as $table)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM '.$table);
    $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);

    $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link,'SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
    $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
            for($j=0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) 
            {
                $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
            }
            $return.= ");\n";
        }
    }

    $return.="\n\n\n";
}

// save file
$path = 'downloads/';
$handle = fopen($path.'db-backup-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');
$filewrite = fwrite($handle,$return);

$fileList = glob('downloads/*.sql');

echo $filename = basename($fileList['0']); 

fclose($handle);`
```

Comment: Maybe use a shell script and just do `mysqldump`?

Comment: or `mysqldump ... | xz -9 > my-dump.sql.xz` to have a smaller dump file. If `xz` is not possible, use ` bzip2`or `gzip`  instead.

Comment: is there any way to do using php without phpmyadmin?

Comment: You could try [this](https://github.com/dimaldim/php-db-exporter)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to phpmyadmin and do a dump, best solution.